# Missing Javascript Files in Nuxt App Deploy to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, webpack, nuxt.js

My nuxt (2.16.3) application deployed to Google App Engine is repeatedly missing two javascript files. It would seem they are produced or expected from webpack (4.46.0).

File names remain consistent and are not part of client.manifest.json. It doesn't appear to be related to any cache. Clearing the browser cache (no CDN) or opening incognito in a new browser/machine does not result in any change.

Current file name example:

- https://.../_nuxt/875bbc0.js
- https://.../_nuxt/615cbed.js

(... is a fully qualified domain)

They are being included in the header of pages:

```
<link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/875bbc0.js" as="script">
```

Files are not in the .nuxt build folder (.nuxt is mapped to _nuxt on deploy), not in the nuxt build output logging, and not referenced in any files the .nuxt build folder. However, my app is non-functional due to the 404's on these missing files.

Is anyone having similar issues or aware of a workaround?

This was a completely working app, and the behavior is new. Local dev environment runs as expected.

As a potential workaround and to ensure it wasn't caching with GAE, I added set a of cache expiration for the js files in app.yaml as well as deleted the existing app engine service and associated dispatch rule. The redeployed as a new GAE service (though with the same name). Still showing the same missing files.

```
  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: .nuxt/dist/client
    secure: always
    expiration: "0d 0h"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some breaking changes in App Engine for Node.js standard environment. Take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/release-notes#April_11_2023).
I had the same issue and was able to solve it with this:

- I've changed `- url: /_nuxt` to `- url: /.nuxt`
- I also added `"gcp-build": ""` to package.json

Comment: Thank you! I didn't need to you change the URL handler, but adding the gcp-build bypass was enough to resolve the issue.